# ActiveAdmin - all types update action show no member in struct

Tags: activeadmin

I am setting up ActiveAdmin and when I use the edit action to update any of my models when I submit it results in an error of the style 'no member '' in struct'. I of course can see that the model_name IS in the structure posted, so I am pretty confused. And I am not sure what I am doing wrong nor how to fix. I have not changed the update action. I am pretty much a Rails newbie, but the active admin is behaving well otherwise. The response for one of these is...

```
NameError in Manage::ProductGroupsController#update
```

no member 'product_group' in struct

Rails.root: /var/hosts/linode_staging/releases/20140218181435/aotv2

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/inherited_resources-e4fb9fc80448/lib/inherited_resources/base_helpers.rb:322:in `[]'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/inherited_resources-e4fb9fc80448/lib/inherited_resources/base_helpers.rb:322:in`build_resource_params'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/inherited_resources-e4fb9fc80448/lib/inherited_resources/base_helpers.rb:316:in `resource_params'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/inherited_resources-e4fb9fc80448/lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:45:in`update'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in`process_action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in`block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run__4471285646399910144__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in`run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in`process_action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in`block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in`instrument'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in`process_action'
activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in`process'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in`dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in`block in action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in`dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in`block in call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in`call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in`block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in`call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in`call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in`context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in`call'
activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in`call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in`*run*_4380831815421705085_*call*_callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in`call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`call_app'
railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in`block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in`tagged'
railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in`call'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in`call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in`call'
railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in`method_missing'
passenger (4.0.37) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:77:in `process_request'
passenger (4.0.37) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:142:in`accept_and_process_next_request'
passenger (4.0.37) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
passenger (4.0.37) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:448:in`block (3 levels) in start_threads'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"p0xsTbNLexYflBaGSCX4KAvp4AGjRNIFueTUoIwAClM=",
 "product_group"=>{"title"=>"REST API",
 "description"=>"The subscriptions for the API",
 "source"=>"tjchambers"},
 "commit"=>"Update Product group",
 "id"=>"9"}
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that you haven't included strong parameters in your product_group.rb
Have a look at this documentation https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters

Should point you into the right direction.

Best,
Jeroen

Comment: I discovered that and was coming back to comment on that when I saw your helpful answer. Thanks!

Comment: you're very welcome. We must have had the issue almost simultaneously :)